# Arguments disappear from callable object

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose you have a function with multiple arguments:

```
def foo(x1, x2, x3, y):
    pass
```

I am trying to make a class, named `FAI`, behave a little like the `functools.partial` function.

```
bar = my_class(foo, 1, 2, 3)
bar("a")
# `bar("a")` supposed to be the same as `foo(1, 2, 3, "a")`
```

When I run the following code:

```
def bar(*args):
    print(args)

bar = FAI(bar, 1)
bar = FAI(bar, 2)
bar = FAI(bar, 3)
bar = FAI(bar, 4)
bar = FAI(bar, 5)
bar = FAI(bar, 6)

bar("a", "b", "c")
```

The `sys.stdout` output I get is:

```
(1, 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

The desired output is one of the following:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b', 'c')
(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

How do I get the desired output?

```
import functools
import inspect

class Meta(type):
    functools=functools
    inspect=inspect
    def __call__(self, imp, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        instance = Klass(imp)
        instance = Klass.__call__(imp)
        instance = Meta.__call__(Klass, imp)
        """
        # `imp`.......`implementation`
        Meta = type(self)
        SuperMeta = Meta.inspect.getmro(Meta)[1]
        inst = SuperMeta.__call__(self, imp, *args, **kwargs)
        inst = functools.update_wrapper(wrapper=inst, wrapped=imp)
        return inst # instance

class FAI(metaclass=Meta):
    """
    `FAI`..........`First argument inputter`
    """
    def __init__(self, imp, arg):
        # `imp`.......`implementation`
        assert (callable(imp))
        self._arg = arg
        self._imp = imp

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._imp(self._arg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Did you do `Meta = type(self)` because you were afraid of trusting the `Meta` global variable? Your attempts to avoid global variable bugs have just caused more bugs. You've reimplemented the common `super(type(self), self)` bug by hand. Also, you forgot to use that `functools` class attribute, instead using the global `functools` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `functools.update_wrapper`. You shouldn't. It's designed to work with functions of the type defined by `def`, not arbitrary callables.

Your `update_wrapper` is copying the `_arg` and `_imp` attributes from old `FAI` instances to new ones, so the last one has the first one's `_arg` and `_imp`.

Also, your `Meta.__call__` has the most bizarrely manual implementation of the `super(type(self), self)` bug I've seen yet. If you ever create a subclass of `Meta` (which can happen without you even noticing, if you don't understand the libraries you use), `SuperMeta` will be `Meta` itself or some other wrong class. Use `super().__call__(imp, *args, **kwargs)` there.